# Concurrent access to pandas.Dataframe slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an application with a shared data (`pandas.DataFrame`). This data is updated from a background task (WebSocket) and also read via web interface. What I noticed, during an update the read is totally blocked.

I update DataFrame using `loc()`, and I have also tried `append()`.

I am using `aiohttp` web framework.

Comment: What's the web framework and application server you're using? Please show some code, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using `aiohttp` web framework.

I assume your code looks something like

```
df = pd.DataFrame()  # Probably loaded from somewhere

async def some_handler(request):
    some_data = get_some_data_from_request()
    for ... in some_data:
      df.loc[...] = ...
    return ...
```

where the `...` elisions are probably rather complex.

Since you're using an [`async`/`await`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) based framework, your views/handlers are run on the same thread as every other request. Since Pandas isn't async at all, the synchronous modification work does indeed block all other requests/responses from happening.

Assuming you are going to run in a single process with a shared dataframe, you'll have to do the synchronous Pandas work in a worker thread. The [`asgiref`](https://github.com/django/asgiref) library (used by e.g. Django) has a neat [sync-to-async](https://github.com/django/asgiref#synchronous-code--threads) wrapper for this, or you can roll your own.

However, there are some gotchas:

- if you modify `df` in-place, other requests may see data that's being currently modified by the worker thread. You can work around *that* by making modifications into a copy of the `df`, then assigning the copy back into place at the end of the work.
- if there are multiple requests that would modify the same data, you'd have multiple worker threads possibly overwriting each others' changes. You can work around that by adding a lock (`threading.Lock()`) that ensures only one thread can be modifying the `df` at once, but that naturally means, well, that only one thread can be modifying it at once.

Good luck.

Comment: You're welcome. Please heed the gotchas too, they will bite you later on if you don't remember them.